# SSIS2005: Importing from multiple XL files/sheets with inconsistent metadata

Tags: excel, ssis, ssis-2005

Thanks in advance for any help anyone can provide,

(Preface:  I'm already familiar with TypeGuessRows registry tweak (I have it set to 0; XL scans the whole column to determine data type) and IMEX=1 extended properties (I use this by default))

I am starting an ongoing project for a client:

- Client sent 10 xlsx files, 1 per year.
- Most, if not all, files have 12 sheets...1 sheet per month.
- All sheets in all files have the exact same number of column with the exact same column headers in the exact same order.
- Client most likely will periodically send new data (hopefully in the same format) over the next 3 years.

Looping through multiple XL files, then looping through multiple XL sheets is not a problem.  I have done that many times in the past.  My SSIS template for XL files is setup that way by default.

The issue I am having is when the data types for the columns can change from sheet to sheet.  For example, on most sheets a date column:

- No NULL/blank dates
- All dates formatted as m/d/yyyy
- XL/SSIS assigns **date [DT_DATE]** data type

...but, on some sheets within the same file, the same date column...

- No NULL/blank dates
- Most dates formatted as m/d/yyyy
- Some dates formatted as general/number (Nov 15, 2002 = 37575)
- XL/SSIS assigns **Unicode string [DT_WSTR]** data type

If I am not mistaken, when I run the SSIS package, it will throw an error when the data types change.

Is it possible force the data type of incoming columns (**Advanced Editor for OLE DB Source** > **Input and Output Properties** sheet > **Inputs and outputs** pane > **OLE DB Source Output** > **External Columns**) to unicode so the package won't error when XL/SSIS wants to change the data type?  This would accommodate all current files and any future ones in case the same inconsistent formatting shows up.

Or am I forced to either:

- Change all general/number formatted dates to a date format so I can import with one SSIS package
- Separate all consistently formatted and inconsistently formatted sheets into 2 separate groups to be imported with 2 different SSIS packages

Once again, Thanks for any help anyone can provide,

CTB

Answer (score 1):

It appears switching from one data type to another won't throw an error, just a warning...at least from **[DT_DATE]** to **[DT_WSTR]** and back.

I was not able to force the data type of the incoming column of the **OLE DB Source**, but I was able to set the outgoing column data type to **[DT_WSTR]** (**Advanced Editor for OLE DB Source** > **Input and Output Properties** sheet > **Inputs and outputs** pane > **OLE DB Source Output** > **Output Columns**).  That way, all dates in that column were seen as unicode text in the data flow, regardless of its source.

That seemed to do the trick.  I needed only one import package to import both types of sheets/files.

I hope this helps someone else in the future...